# Server Client Program with FIFO and Struct using while loop

Tags: c, structure, fifo, mkfifo

I’m able to pass a struct through my fifo, but how would I go about making my program keep on going back and forth from the client to the server until the client decides to exit the program.

I’ve tried it with a while loop but it just doesn’t seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.it will run the program but wont pass the data to the through the fifo. Without the while loop the data is passed. any help or tips will be appreciated

Client Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Client {
    int clientNum;
    int systemCall;
    int num;
    int result;
} client;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   if (mkfifo("ClientFifo", 0777) == -1) {
       if (errno != EEXIST) {
           printf("Could not create fifo file\n");
           return 1;
       }
       printf("Opened\n");
       int fd = open("ClientFifo", O_RDONLY);
       if (fd == -1) {
           return 1;
       }
       //while statement
       while(1) {
           printf("Reading\n");
           read(fd, &client, sizeof(client)); 
           printf("Client number:  %d\n", client.clientNum);
           printf("System call number:  %d\n", client.systemCall);
           printf("Parameter number %d\n", client.num);
           printf("Result %d\n", client.result); 
           close(fd);
       } //while
       return 0;
   } //end if   
} //end main
```

Server Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Client {
    int clientNum;
    int systemCall;
    int num;
    int result;
} client;

struct Client get_student_data()
{
    struct Client s;
    s.clientNum = getpid();
    printf("Client Number:%d", s.clientNum);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter System Call number:");
    scanf("%d", &s.systemCall);
    printf("Enter Number:");
    scanf("%d", &s.num);
    printf("system call:%d\n", s.systemCall);

    switch (s.systemCall)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Youre in case 1\n");
        s.result = s.num * s.num; 
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Youre in case 2\n");
        s.result = s.num * s.num * s.num;
        break;
    default:
        printf("INVALID CHOICE\n");
        s.result = 0;
        break;
    }
    
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {//main
   
   //makes fifo  
   if(mkfifo("ClientFifo", 0777) == -1) {
       //error message in case fifo isnt created
       if(errno != EEXIST) {
           printf("Could not create fifo file\n");
           return 1;
       }//end error checking
 
       //area to do work
       printf("\n");

       //while Statement
       while(client.systemCall != 0) {

           struct Client c1 = get_student_data();
           printf("\nClient number: %d\n",c1.clientNum);
           printf("System call number: %d\n",c1.systemCall);
           printf("Paramet number: %d\n",c1.num);
           printf("Result number: %d\n",c1.result);
    
    
           //opens and closes FIFO
           printf("Opening...\n");
           int fd = open("ClientFifo", O_WRONLY);
           printf("Opened\n");

           if(write(fd, &c1, sizeof(c1)) == -1) {
               return 2;
           }
           //}//ends write
           //Closes fd
           printf("Written..\n");
           close(fd);
       }
       return 0;
   } //ends if fifo    
} //ends main
```

Placed while loop where placed in code but doesn't run correctly

Comment: Your formatting is terrible, but it looks like in both programs you have a loop but you close `fd` in the first iteration.

Comment: Formatting and identation is terrible. Does this program even compile?

Comment: How does your current code behave? Are you getting an error, or unexpected behavior? What attempt have you made to debug the problem?

Comment: The code runs fine without the while loop. It takes the input from the user and passes it through the fifo to the client. 

I just want to add the option to run the switch more than once and add a case that lets the user exit when that option is chosen

Comment: If you want to continue to use the fifo then don't close it until you are really finished which is probably outside the loop.